# custom directive required params

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

can we create a custom directive set as an element with required parameters , so that if these params are not provided by who ever would like to use it... then the directive must not work ???

```
**JS:**

 app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            scope : {
                data       :  "=data", ... 
            } , 
           templateUrl: function(element, attr) {
               // HTML file path 
             }, 
           ....
    }
 });
```

the case is now even if these params are not passed , the directive still works and injects the html in the view .

This is a generic question about directive not related to this specific case only .

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own validation in the link function

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
           scope : {
                data       :  "=data", ... 
           } , 
           templateUrl: function(element, attr) {
               // HTML file path 
           }, 
           link: function(scope, element, attrs){
               if(!data){
                   element.remove();
               }
           }
    }
 });
```

I'm not sure if there's a more official way though

Comment: no i dont think removing the DOM after its added is useful ,, maybe if its in the controller then we can validate before the element gets added @Kevin F